# get closing Tag Java using jSoup

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I'm working on a programm that is scanning a website and looking for mistakes
The htmls are parsed with *jSoup*.

Is there a way to get not the opening tag but just the *closing tag*
to check if the amount of opening tags equals the amount of closing tags?

*d.select("/tag")* does not work

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think jSoup is the best way to go.
I would check tidy lib [like jTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net)